# ng-repeat data binding with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list and on each item in list I am calling a modal window (custom directive) which should have details about that item being clicked , but the data does not change and remains same across each item. Please find the code below.

```
 angular
.module('Testapp')
.directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "/Apps/templates/mytem/testdir.html",
        translucent: true,
        scope: {item:'=data'},
        link: function (scope, element, attribute) {
            console.log(scope.sequence);
        }
    };
});
```

**Directive**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalAddFilters">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body tree"> 
  {{item}} 
   </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Calling Template

```
<div>
<div ng-repeat="items in TestList>
<test-Directive   id="directive_modalAddFilters"  data="items"></test-Directive>
</div>
```

I am able to see the **data correctly loaded in DOM** but directive template doesnt change the data.

Comment: 1. could you create a fiddle with your code?, 2. `"` missing in `<div ng-repeat="items in TestList>` and 3. use `id="directive_modalAddFilters_{{$index}}"` within a `ng-repeat` to prevent duplicate IDs

Comment: What do you mean by "directive template doesnt change the data."? Also fix the casing in `test-Directive`, it needs to be `test-directive`.

Comment: Thanks @DonJuwe , it also worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine, except that you forget to close you `ng-repeat` with a quotation mark.

I think you just didn't properly resolved you data into the modal view.

I have made a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JchMm5X6D0IiseFsdrDG?p=preview) based on your (partial) code, I added a modal and everything works fine. I've used ui-bootstrap to show the modal with the repeated data injected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @svarog..It worked...i was not passing the object in on click function